# Mi aplicación se detuvo al cambiar de pestaña

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un problema y quisiera saber si podrían darme una mano.
Estoy trabajando con un proyecto, mi aplicación funciona perfectamente en mi celular al emularla, es API 19. Le mande el proyecto a un amigo y luego de la "SplashActivity" pasa a la ventana principal llamada "Primera" e instantáneamente se le cierra con el mensaje "Lo sentimos la aplicación se detuvo". Mande a otro amigo el proyecto y también le pasa lo mismo, el cual tiene API 24. Todos los celulares que probe API 19 anda mi aplicación, de y las versiones mas nuevas sale ese mensaje. Revise el código de la ventana llamada "Primera" y no encuentro ningún error es una pestaña simple con botones. Desearía si me pudieran dar una mano.

Build Graddle:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tam.noc.nooctambulos"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled = true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Actividad "Primera" donde se produce error:

```
public class Primera extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton mapa;
    ImageButton boliches;
    ImageButton contacto;
    ImageButton sugerencia;
    ImageButton previa;
    ImageView titulo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_primera);
        //Boliches
        boliches = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bolichesybaresbutton);
        boliches.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Primera.this, Boliches.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //Titulo
        titulo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.titulo);

        //Mapa
        mapa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mapabutton);
        mapa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Primera.this, MapsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        //Contacto
        contacto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttoncontacto);
        contacto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Primera.this, Contacto.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Sugerencia
        sugerencia = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonsugerencia);
        sugerencia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Primera.this, Sugerencias.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Previa
        previa = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonprevia);
        previa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Primera.this, Previa.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tam.noc.nooctambulos">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Primera"
            android:label="Noc"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Boliches"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_boliches"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Contacto"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contacto"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Sugerencias"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sugerencias"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Previa"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_previa"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Splashsuper"
            android:label="Noctambulos"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".juegos"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_juegos"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".tragos"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tragos"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
    </application>
```

Y en el LOGCAT dice esto:

```
04-03 19:05:45.020 513-513/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-03 19:05:46.163 513-513/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
04-03 19:05:46.163 513-513/? W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-03 19:06:05.314 2981-2981/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
04-03 19:06:05.314 2981-2981/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
04-03 19:06:05.329 2981-2981/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                       adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.ftw_and_co.happn
04-03 19:09:32.881 4755-4434/? V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 19343043
04-03 19:09:37.885 4755-4434/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-03 19:09:40.219 4611-4619/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-03 19:09:40.220 4611-4619/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
04-03 19:09:40.220 4611-4619/? W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

Comment: Decir que se detuvo es demasiado amplio, en ocasiones no es posible detectar rápidamente un problema, para eso necesitamos del mensaje desplegado en LogCat. Si deseas desarrollar en Android el uso del LogCat es requerimiento importante para evitar perder tiempo en adivinar que es lo que sucede.

Comment: Ahí añadí en LogCat, es todo lo que sale hasta que la app se cierra luego del SplashActivity. Analizarlo por favor y si puedes darme una mano te lo agradecería.

Comment: No encontraste una linea donde dice "Caused by" ?

Comment: No solamente dice eso copie todo lo que dice en el LogCat, por lo que entiendo dice que se filtro un archivo que esta causando ese problema la verdad desconozco de este error, en las API 19 funciona perfectamente y de ahi en adelante sucede ese error.